# Como rodar o php artisan migrate no servidor web

Tags: php, laravel

Passei o projeto do **Laravel 5.4** para a hospedagem, porém agora não conheço uma forma de usar o **php artisan migrate** para criar minhas tabelas no banco de dados.

Criei um arquivo na pasta public com o nome de **installation.php** com o seguinte código:

```
<?php 
   // installation.php file
   echo exec('php /var/www/laravel-app/artisan migrate:install');
```

Dessa forma quando acessado este arquivo automaticamente fossem migradas minhas tabelas. Obtive o seguinte retorno:

```
Warning: exec(): Unable to fork [php /home/MEU_ENDEREÇO/public_html/PROJETO/artisan migrate:install] in /home/MEU_ENDEREÇO/public_html/PROJETO/public/installation.php on line 3
```

Gostaria de saber as formas que posso executar tal procedimento ou para resolver este erro.

Att. Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Não consegue fazer isso por `ssh`?

Comment: Desculpe, não sei fazer dessa forma :D

Comment: Deve ter algum tutorial no seu serviço de hospedagem.

Comment: da uma olhada na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php) do `exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )` tem mais dois parametros que voce pode usar, `$output` é o retorno do comando, a saida que voce vê no terminal, isso vai te dar uma ideia melhor do que esta acontecendo.

Comment: Outro problema que pode ser é que algumas hospedagens tem o PHP 5.2 instalado, mas com `.htaccess` habilitando para executar como 5.3, 5.4, etc. O problema disso é que ao executar o `artisan` pela linha de comando, que é o que o `exec()` faz, vai executar como PHP 5.2 e portanto dar um monte de erro por que o laravel precisa de no minimo PHP 5.3, nesse caso eu não sei se tem como resolver.

Comment: Entrei em contato com a hospedagem e pedi para liberarem o acesso ssh, à partir deste momento foi só rodar os comandos do php artisan.

Agradeço a colaboração, foi de grande ajuda.

Comment: Poderia, tambem exportar o banco no phpmyadmin local e depois importar no phpmyadmin  no seu hospedeiro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entrei em contato com minha hospedagem e habilitei o ssh, após isso foi apenas necessário executar os comandos do php artisan que tudo funcionou perfeitamente.

Agradeço a todos que colaboraram e ao @Anderson Carlos Woss que comentou sobre o ssh da hospedagem